# How do I compile gcc-5 from source?

Tags: linux, debian, gcc

It looks like gcc-5 was recently removed from Debian's unstable repository. I need gcc-5 to compile an older Linux kernel (3.19) and so I am looking to build it from source, through this is causing me a great deal of trouble. I have been following the instructions found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html), but I find myself wondering what settings I need to set and more. Thus far, I have done the following.

1. Downloaded and unpacked the source code.
2. Configured gcc-5 by doing the following:

```
% mkdir objdir
% cd objdir
% ../gcc-5.4.0/configure (I included neither options nor target flags)
```

3. Attempted to build using the following in my `objdir` directory:

```
% make BOOT_CFLAGS='-O' bootstrap
```

However, bootstrapping raised errors that prevented me from moving onto the install. After running for about 5 minutes, I encounter the following errors:

```
In file included from ../../../../gcc-5.4.0/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c:401:0:
./md-unwind-support.h: In function 'x86_fallback_frame_state':
./md-unwind-support.h:141:18: error: field 'uc' has incomplete type
struct ucontext uc;
                ^
make[5]: *** [../../../../gcc-5.4.0/libgcc/shared-object.mk:14: unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/me/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgcc'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1154: multi-do] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/me/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:119: multi-do] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/me/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:16510: all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/me/objdir'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22461: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:22798: bootstrap] Error 2
```

I am running Debian 10 (Buster) and have the necessary prerequisites installed as listed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html).

Any help or guidance either in fixing the errors I have during bootstrapping or with building from source in general would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Build gcc-5.4.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/18QF-83jzDLfA9jSMn4KvvuTkKiY2nm9u/view?usp=sharing .... Not tested with gcc-8 as the "build compiler" : You may have to use gcc-4.8? .... .... Please note that "no options" will fail.

Comment: @KnudLarsen and how do we install gcc-4.8?

Comment: Consider using gcc in docker. It has versions going back to 6.5 I don't see version 5 in there though. (but maybe you can build from 6.5, @KnudLarsen did not reference what version we can use). Unofficial gcc-5 docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/purplekarrot/gcc-5/

Comment: Gcc-4.8 : You can use the package `gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb` ... Also usable with Debian : No dependencies (except libc6 >= 2.14) Provides `/usr/local/bin/{gcc48, g++48}` ... Link to extra "Debian compilers" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ... ( gcc-5.4.0 is also available.)

Comment: You can't compiler newer versions of GCC with older versions of GCC without patches.

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen, your gcc-4.8 package worked for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that there were changes in glibc, which broke compatibility with old compilers. There exists a [patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=gcc.git;h=883312dc79806f513275b72502231c751c14ff72) for those compilers. The patch replaces `struct ucontext` with `ucontext_t` in `libgcc/config/<arch>/linux-unwind.h` files, where `<arch>` is `i386`, `aarch64`, `alpha` etc.

There is a similar [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52498431/compile-gcc6-4-0-using-gcc8-1-1).

I addition to these fixes, I also needed to apply fixes for sanitizers code from [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/822) (some of them were enough) and [here](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/patch/6824253.3U2boEivI2@devpool21/).

After that the GCC has been finally built.

Comment: Its curious why they release a version that doesn't compile?

Comment: @jerseybean The GCC version did compile at the time of release. But later glibc broke compatibility at some point and after that time old versions of GCC stopped compiling with newer versions of glibc. I'm not exactly sure as to why glibc did that. Probably it had something to do with POSIX compliance. You can try to google it yourself, e.g. starting [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=sysdeps/i386/sys/ucontext.h;h=251287734e89a52da3db682a8241eb6bccc050c9).